# MegaMenu JS - right aligned

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, megamenu

I am using MegaMenu JS to create a large drop down menu on hover.
I want to right align the menu so that the menu items are on the right side of the menu. I have tried adding **pull-right**, but that makes the drop down pull-right as well and not 100% width. I have also tried using a **row** with different **col** sizes but this also causes the drop down to be sized to that column size and the goal is to have the drop down 100% width on hover.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  "use strict";

  $('.menu > ul > li:has( > ul)').addClass('menu-dropdown-icon');

  $('.menu > ul > li > ul:not(:has(ul))').addClass('normal-sub');

  $(".menu > ul").before("<a href=\"#\" class=\"menu-mobile\"></a>");

  $(".menu > ul > li").hover(function(e) {
    if ($(window).width() > 943) {
      $(this).children("ul").stop(true, false).fadeToggle(150);
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });

  $(".menu > ul > li").click(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 943) {
      $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
    }
  });

  $(".menu-mobile").click(function(e) {
    $(".menu > ul").toggleClass('show-on-mobile');
    e.preventDefault();
  });


});
```

```css
header {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff !important;
}

.menu-container {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #fff;
}

.menu-mobile {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

.menu-mobile:after {
  content: "\f0c9";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-25%);
}

.menu-dropdown-icon:before {
  content: "\f067";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  padding: 1.5em 2em;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  position: static !important;
}

.menu>ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  /* IF .menu position=relative -> ul = container width, ELSE ul = 100% width */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu>ul:before,
.menu>ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.menu>ul:after {
  clear: both;
}

.menu>ul>li {
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu>ul>li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1.5em 3em;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.menu>ul>li a:hover {
  background: transparent;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul:before,
.menu>ul>li>ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul:after {
  clear: both;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul>li {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 25%;
  background: none;
  float: left;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul>li span {
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul>li a {
  padding: .2em 0;
  width: 95%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul>li>ul {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul>li>ul:before,
.menu>ul>li>ul>li>ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul>li>ul:after {
  clear: both;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li a {
  border: 0;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul.normal-sub {
  width: 300px;
  left: auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul.normal-sub>li {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul.normal-sub>li a {
  border: 0;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
  .menu-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-dropdown-icon:before {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu {
    z-index: 999;
  }
  .menu>ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu>ul>li {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .menu>ul>li a {
    padding: 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  .menu>ul>li a:hover {
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }
  .menu>ul>li>ul {
    position: relative;
  }
  .menu>ul>li>ul.normal-sub {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu>ul>li>ul>li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .menu>ul>li>ul>li:first-child {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .menu>ul>li>ul>li>ul {
    position: relative;
  }
  .menu>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li {
    float: none;
  }
  .menu .show-on-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <header>
    <nav role="navigation">
         <a href="#">LOGO HERE</a>
          <div class="menu-container">
            <div class="menu">
              <ul>
                   <li>
                  <a href="#">Products</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <h4 class="heading-responsive"><span class="text-dark text-thick">Product</span></h4>
                      <ul class="text-center">
                        <li>Desc</li>
                      </ul>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <h4 class="heading-responsive"><span class="text-dark text-thick">Product</span></h4>
                      <ul class="text-center">
                        <li>Desc</li>
                      </ul>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <h4 class="heading-responsive"><span class="text-dark text-thick">Product</span></h4>
                      <ul class="text-center">
                        <li>Desc</li>
                      </ul>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <h4 class="heading-responsive"><span class="text-dark text-thick">Product</span></h4>
                      <ul class="text-center">
                        <li>Desc</li>
                      </ul>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                           <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Support</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

(view snippet in full width so you can see it without the mobile styles).
How can I have the menu items on the right side of the screen without causing the drop down to not be full width from side to side?

Comment: Did you manage to get this fixed? I have the same issue.

Comment: No I haven't been able to fix it. I have it left aligned for now.